# Assigning Parse Array to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

I've successfully managed pointing my Parse Data Strings to UILabels and having them display the content on a UITableViewController.

On my UITableView Cell I also have a UITextView to display an Array from Parse.  This Array is called "Post_Description".  Within my cell on Storyboard I have given my UITextView a tag of 103.

However when I run this code, I'm getting a crash.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170239c60'
```

Here is the code i am calling for the UITextView:

```
    UITextView *postView = (UITextView*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
postView.text = [object objectForKey:@"Post_Description"];
```

[image]

[image: Parse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good because I ended up figuring this out by myself after digging deep into some material.

First you create your UITextView identifier and point to the cell tag of your UITextView:

```
UITextView *myTextView = (UITextView*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
```

Then you assign an NSArray to your Array in Parse:

```
NSArray *myArray = [object objectForKey:@"MyArrayInParse"];
```

Then you join them in marriage like so:

```
[myTextView setText:[myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
```

And that's how you display an Array in Parse, into a UITextView :)