# Assigning NSArray to UITextView Parse findObjectsInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsarray, uitextview

I have a UITextView on a View Controller.  This UITextView is called statusTextView.

I have a column under my Parse Class "User" called "Status"

I'm having a hard time getting the NSArray into a UITextView.

Here's what I have:

**Properties:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *statusTextView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *status;
```

**viewDidAppear:**

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"Status" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        self.status = objects;
        statusTextView.text =[status componentsJoinedByString:@"%@"];
    }
}];
```

I've figured this out for a UITableViewController [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506566/assigning-parse-array-to-uitextview)

If there is a way to do this easier I would greatly appreciate the help.

**What else I have tried:**

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"Status" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        self.statusTextView.text = object[@"Status"];
    });


}];
```

Comment: Why is status an array of users?

Comment: @Wain Perhaps i'm doing it wrong, i'm new to programming.  My Status column under User is an Array.  Then I thought I had to create an NSArray in my app to accept the Status array from Parse, and then push the NSArray (status) to my UITextView (statusTextView).

Comment: Why is the status column an array? Explain your data model. How are you anticipating this array being displayed in text?

Comment: @Wain So when I went to prepare the UIViewController on the MainStoryBoard I wanted to make sure that the users text fit completely inside the view.  Being that the User would be setting a status, I figured I couldn't use a label, because you cannot have user interaction with a UILabel (as far as I know) for them to edit it.  Then I wanted to go with a UITextField and found out that I am restricted with a textfield to one row of text.  So that landed me on a UITextView, and I liked that I could increase or decrease the amount of space required for text with a UITextView.

Comment: @Wain  So I had to create my Parse Column and knew in order for it to go to a UITextView that I needed an Array (maybe this isn't true, perhaps I should have made it a String?).  So my thought process was that I had an Array of text coming from Parse.  That I had to assign this Parse Array to an NSArray, so that I could assign the NSArray to my UITextView.  This way the user status shows in the View Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having this problem, here is the solution that I came up with which is pretty simple.  So you have added a Parse Column to your "User" Class.  You want to call this column to fill a UITextView.

For me I wanted my current user to be able to set a social status.  So I created a Column under my "User" Class in Parse called "Status" and assigned it as a String.

**1)  I dragged a UITextView into my View Controller using Storyboards.**

**2)  I then made the property:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *statusTextView;
```

**3) Then I synthesized this property:**

```
@synthesize statusTextView;
```

**4) Then I created a method called loadUser:**

```
- (void)loadUser
{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    statusTextView.text = user[@"Status"];
}
```

**5) Then I made sure to call this method in my viewDidAppear:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[self loadUser];
}
```

That's it.  Hope this helps :)